# Bokeh: How to add a legend and custom color boundaries to an image plot?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a two-dimensional array that I want to plot using bokeh's `bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.image`. It works wonderful.

Now, I want to add a legend using the colors used for the image. I don't find any example for my case. The legend that I'd like to achieve is similar to the picture.

[image: example plot]

```
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper, ColorBar
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

plot = figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1), toolbar_location="right")
color_mapper =  LinearColorMapper(palette="YlGn9", low=-1, high=1, nan_color="white")
plot.image(image=[ndvi], color_mapper=color_mapper,dh=[1.0], dw=[1.0], x=[0], y=[0])

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper,label_standoff=12, border_line_color=None, location=(0,0))

plot.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
```

Additionally, I'd like to have some custom color boundaries, with non-fixed intervals. Here is an example how it would be done with matplotlib:

```py
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['#27821f', '#3fa336', '#6ce362','#ffffff','#e063a8' ,'#cc3b8b','#9e008c','#59044f'])
bounds = [-1000, -500, -100, 0, 50, 100, 300, 500, 10000000]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose the red-yellow-green palette. In bokeh the name is 'RdYlGn5', where the digit at the end tells how many colors are needed. To use it in a legend, you'ld need to import `RdYlGn5` from `bokeh.palettes`.

For creating the legend, I only know of employing some dummy glyphs as in the code below.

I updated my example with the new requirements of setting custom bounds with non-fixed intervals. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58159110/how-to-create-a-proportional-pre-defined-boundaries-colour-bar-with-bokeh) offers some guidance. Basically, the idea is to use a larger colormap with repeated colors. Such a format doesn't fit for general types of boundaries, but it fits yours, at least when the lowest and highest bound are interpreted to be infinite.

I also tried to layout the legend with some custom spaces to get all labels aligned. A background color is chosen to contrast with the legend entries.

There is a colorbar to verify how the colormap bounds work internally. After verification, you may leave it out. The example image has values from -1000 to 1000 to show how the values outside the strict colormap limits are handled.

Here is an example with dummy data:

```py
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper, Legend, LegendItem, ColorBar, SingleIntervalTicker
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 10, 1000), np.linspace(0, 10, 1000))
z = 1000*np.sin(x + np.cos(y))

plot = figure(x_range=(0, 1), y_range=(0, 1), toolbar_location="right")
base_colors = ['#27821f', '#3fa336', '#6ce362','#ffffff','#e063a8' ,'#cc3b8b','#9e008c','#59044f']
bounds = [-1000, -500, -100, 0, 50, 100, 300, 500, 10000000]
low = -600
high = 600
bound_colors = []
j = 0
for i in range(low, high, 50):
    if i >= bounds[j+1]:
        j += 1
    bound_colors.append(base_colors[j])
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=bound_colors, low=low, high=high, nan_color="white")

plot.image(image=[z], color_mapper=color_mapper, dh=[1.0], dw=[1.0], x=[0], y=[0])

# these are a dummy glyphs to help draw the legend
dummy_for_legend = [plot.line(x=[1, 1], y=[1, 1], line_width=15, color=c, name='dummy_for_legend')
                    for c in base_colors]
legend_labels = [f'     < {bounds[1]}'] + \
                [('' if l < 0 else '     ' if l < 10 else '   ' if l < 100 else ' ')
                 + f'{l} ‒ {h}' for l, h in zip(bounds[1:], bounds[2:-1])] + \
                [f'     > {bounds[-2]}']

legend1 = Legend(title="NDVI", background_fill_color='gold',
                 items=[LegendItem(label=lab, renderers=[gly]) for lab, gly in zip(legend_labels, dummy_for_legend) ])
plot.add_layout(legend1)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=12, border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0),
                     ticker=SingleIntervalTicker(interval=50))
plot.add_layout(color_bar)

show(plot)
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much, it means a lot for me, thank you.
if you dont mind i wanna ask one more thing related to bokeh, how i can make custom color mapper like setting bounds in matplotlib ? it look like this in matplotlib

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['#27821f', '#3fa336', '#6ce362','#ffffff','#e063a8' ,'#cc3b8b','#9e008c','#59044f'])

bounds = [-1000,-500,-100, 0,50, 100,300,500, 10000000]

norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

Comment: I'm looking into your new question. Still exploring. The closest I found is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58159110/how-to-create-a-proportional-pre-define-boundaries-colour-bar-with-python-boke  I'm creating an example with your boundaries.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, i really really appreciate it, it helped me a lot, THANKS

Comment: HI, i wanna ask another question but still related to bokeh, so i'm developing my dynamic web app using flask where it will do image processing and serve the processed result using bokeh. I want to know if bokeh run in back end or front end, i use amazon server with quite high specification but when i access it from my pc the graphic never come out, the data is quite large, in the form of array its 7000 x 7000. my pc is quite low at specification, and when i access the web from my pc,

Comment: my cpu process indicator run quite high when the web is serving the bokeh, and drop low when the process has already done (but the bokeh never come out at my browser) so i assume that the plotting process is done in client, but im not really sure yet. If its true that it runs on client side, is there any other option how to run it on back end ? im not really sure about this because im still beginner so i hope you can give me advices, thanks in advance. PS. im sorry for my broken english, i hope you can get what im trying to say